# Retrieving files from another URL on the server

Tags: .htaccess

I have one server two domains. I need the images and css apply to both domains. Currently I solve it using htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^.*\.(css)$ http://www.rs.cz/style/$0 [L,R]`

How is it possible to improve? Or at least refer to a relative path on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Create one subdomain just for hosting images and static content like:
images.mydomain1.com
and another subdomain like:
images.mydomain2.com
Have both of them redirect to the same directory in the server like /var/www/common_images.